# Исправление лексических ошибок

Tags: лексика

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли я исправила лексические ошибки? Заранее большое спасибо!

1. Долг врача – не отмахиваться от больного, а довести его до конца. (Врач обязан следить за состоянием больных до полного их выздоровления.)
2. Вечер, посвященный юбилею поэта, состоится сегодня утром. (Сегодня состоится вечер, посвященный юбилею поэта.)
3. Мы уделяем большое значение образованию наших студентов. (Мы уделяем большое значение качеству образования наших студентов.)
4. Достоевский – писатель-психиатр занимает достойное место среди выдающихся мастеров слова. (Писатель Достоевский  занимает достойное место среди выдающихся мастеров слова.)
5. Я знаю, что живы предки Пушкина. (Я знаю, что еще живы предки Пушкина.)
6. Нужно воздать дань этой жемчужине среди славянских библиотек. (Нужно воздать должное этой жемчужине среди славянских библиотек.)
7. Подсознание имеет большую роль в жизни человека. (Подсознание играет большую роль в жизни человека.)

Answer (score 1):

Предки Пушкина не могут быть живы. Замените их на потомков.

Answer (score 1):

Во втором предложении при исправлении утратилась информативность, лучше - "Мероприятие, посвящённое юбилею поэта, состоится сегодня утром". 
В четвёртом тоже мысль при исправлении урезали. Лучше - "Достоевский – писатель-психолог, занимает достойное место среди выдающихся мастеров слова".
Ну, и в пятом предложении предки Пушкина, который поэт XIX века, до наших дней не дожили. В предложении видимо имеются в виду потомки.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!Я с вами согласна!!!

Comment: 3. Третье предложение не сразу заметил, см ответ виктор1799

Comment: Достоевский – писатель-психолог, занимает достойное место среди выдающихся мастеров слова".

Либо приложение _писатель-психолог_ выделяем парным тире, либо двумя запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

3.Мы уделяем большое значение образованию наших студентов. (Мы уделяем большое значение качеству образования наших студентов ( уделяем внимание или придаем значение)

2.Вечер, посвященный юбилею поэта, состоится сегодня утром. (Сегодня утром состоится празднование юбилея поэта.)

Comment: Народ, да не делайте вы за него домашние задания!! Пусть сам думает, а то потом вырастают недоросли, не способные собственное имя без ошибок написать!!

Comment: Так он как раз сам думает. Он же просит проверить свои ответы.

Comment: Ладно, тут — так и быть. Тут человек хоть попросил. А то обычно напишут задание: решайте за него.